# How to Outputting PDFs with Django?

Tags: python, django, pdf, django-views, pdf-generation

I am referring this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/ for pdf generation with reportlab.

```
def some_view(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'

    # Create the PDF object, using the response object as its "file."
    p = canvas.Canvas(response)

    # Draw things on the PDF. Here's where the PDF generation happens.
    # See the ReportLab documentation for the full list of functionality.
    p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")

    # Close the PDF object cleanly, and we're done.
    logging.debug('-----p---')
    logging.debug(p)
    p.showPage()
    p.save()
    return response
```

**If I add this reportlab folder in myapp then it is giving this error:**

```
ViewDoesNotExist at /aps/print-pdf/
Could not import myapp.views. Error was: No module named reportlab
```

**And if I put this reportlab folder out of myapp folder then it is giving this error:**

```
ViewDoesNotExist at /aps/print-pdf/
Tried some_view in module myapp.views. Error was: 'HardenedModulesHook' object has no attribute '_files'
```

What is wrong in this? Please help.

Comment: How you installed reportlab? Do you use virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

1. check `myapp` is in your settings.INSTALLED_APPS?
2. check `reportlab` is successfully installed in your python environment, use `pip freeze` or run a python shell to see if `import reportlab` can work